# Decoding Google safe browsing v3 protocol buffers

Tags: c#, google-api, protocol-buffers, safe-browsing, protobuf-csharp-port

I am trying to decode the protocol buffers returned from Google's Safe Browsing API.

I am using C#, but a Java solution would work also as it would be more or less the same.

My current incomplete code is like this

```
    public void Download()
    {
        var lists = new List<string>
        {
            "goog-malware-shavar",
            "goog-unwanted-shavar",
            "googpub-phish-shavar"
        };
        var protocol = "https://";
        var uriBase = $"safebrowsing.google.com/safebrowsing/downloads?client=api&key={_googleSafeBrowsingApiKey}&appver=1.5.2&pver=3.0";
        var requestUrl = protocol + uriBase;
        var content = new StringContent("googpub-phish-shavar;\ngoog-malware-shavar;\ngoog-unwanted-shavar;\n");
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var httpResult = client.PostAsync(requestUrl, content).Result;
            var result = httpResult.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            var lines = result.Split('\n');
            var firstUrl = lines[2].Substring(2);
            var newRes = client.GetAsync("https://" + firstUrl).Result.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync().Result;
            var len = BitConverter.ToUInt32(newRes, 0);
            var newArray = newRes.Skip(3).Take((int)len).ToArray();
            try
            {
                ChunkData chunk =
                ChunkData.Parser.ParseFrom(newArray);
                if (chunk == null)
                {

                }
            }
            catch
            {

            }
        }

    }
```

I am not really sure what to pass to ChunkData.Parser.ParseFrom

According to the documentation the result is supposed to start with an unsigned 32-bit integer, so that why I used var len = BitConverter.ToUInt32(newRes, 0), to try and get this number. I thought this should be the number of bytes in the chunk, but this number is much larger than the whole byte array.

How can I get the correct pieces of the byte array to the ChunkData parser?

Comment: Most probably, an issue with **endianness**. Check the documentation https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.bitconverter(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Yes. The endianness was the problem. Thanks.